# Mvc Application, user authentication STS (ADFS)

Tags: authentication, claims-based-identity, adfs

In MVC Application, user authentication `STS (ADFS)` working for one `ADFS`, but I want to change the all parameter at run time for different `ADFS` which are configured in `Web.config` like this :

authority name
validIssuers
issuer (in `system.identityModel.services` section)
etc

Answer (score 1):

I'm done with this issue.
we can change all following parameters dynamically as below:

```
FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.IssuerNameRegistry = new Trust(trust);
FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri("https://localhost:44300"));
FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.PassiveRedirectEnabled = true;
FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.Issuer = "https://sts.domainame.com/adfs/ls/";
FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.Realm = "https://localhost:44300";
```

Trust Class:

```
public class Trust : IssuerNameRegistry
{
    string trust;
    public Trust(string trust)
    {
        this.trust= trust;
    }
    public override string GetIssuerName(SecurityToken securityToken)
    {
        return trust;
    }
}
```